# Remove all filters from a single column - tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I've read the documentation and I know I can remove a filter like this:

```
table.removeFilter("age", ">", 22);
```

(assuming I have the filter >22 on my age column).
or remove all filters from the table like this:

```
table.clearFilter();
```

But what if I want to remove only the filters on my age column, but I cannot be sure what these are. I have filters based on a dropdown, so sometimes I might not have 22 in that space. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
table.clearColumnFilters("age");
```

or

```
table.removeFilter("age", ">", *);
```

(Where * is a wildcard)

I don't want to remove the filters on my other columns, so blanking the whole table is no good.
What I have now is a removeFilter for every possible input value - but my dropdown is going to expand, I can't just keep adding removeFilters for each item.

Is there some way of clearing all the filters?

Comment: You could use `.getFilters()` and step through the array and `.removeFilter()` for any with the appropriate field.

Comment: This is pretty much what I did , went for a walk and it hit me as obvious. I should answer my own question so if anyone else gets frustrated by this they can see it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a way to do this no bother:

```
var allFilters = table.getFilters();
        for (var filter = 0; filter< allFilters.length; filter+=1){
            if (allFilters[filter]['field'] === "age"){
               table.removeFilter("age",allFilters[filter['type'],allFilters[filter]['value']);
            }
        }
```

Loop through the filters, if it matches the column you want to "unfilter" then remove it.